# How to disable tips or explanations

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code

I'm using VSC latest version on OSX Big Sur,  with the Python extension and a couple of theme and icon extensions.

I'm not sure if the extra information shown below for the print function and others can be turned off.

If so and someone knows the proper name and how to disable them I'd appreciate it.

Thank you

[image]